# I need to edit time in the 24 hour format, in my main xml for android

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm creating a app, whereby I want people to be able to edit the times that something took place. I want to implement this in the smallest way in my main.xml layout.

### **First**:

My first thought has just been to find a widget like a scrollable clock, such as android offers in the regular XML layout editor on eclipse. My issue with that one is that it has an AM/PM button beside it. I'd rather do 24 hour clock (it will take up less room).

### **Second**:

Whether or not I can find something like that, is this the best way to do a UI editing of time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the normal TimePicker that you saw, but set this to true: [setIs24HourPicker()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html#setIs24HourView%28java.lang.Boolean%29)

There might be a corresponding XML attribute to do that in your XML instead of doing it programatically, but I can't find it.